# compare two images using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-comparison

I want to compare two images using OpenCV. Could I filter the nearest matching result among other training data set..?
Example : the Database containing training image which show number 5 in using one hand.

Is it possible to match someone else ,same sign with that training image..? 
Using OpenCV. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like sinelaw said, there is no straightforward, easy solution **in general**.

However, I can think of one simple way that would work for your **specific example**.

- Detect areas corresponding to human skin in the image.  This is assuming the person isn't wearing gloves (if they are, knowing the color of the gloves will help).  See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422340/skin-color-detection) on skin detection.  Basically, you convert your image into YUV and threshold using the chrominance, because it is known that human skin occupies only a small part of the chroma spectrum, regardless of race
- Detect contours.  In OpenCV, this is done using cvFindContours function.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785419/detection-of-coins-and-fit-ellipses-on-an-image) of that function being used to find ellipses.  You're interested in contours of any shape, not just ellipses at this point.
- Now, go through all your contours, and look for a contour that looks like an open hand making the 5 signal.  This isn't as hard as this sounds, because you're after a convex hull (red outline) with a 4-5 convexity defects (the black arrows):

[image: convexity defects]

- The image above is from the [OpenCV API](https://picoforge.int-evry.fr/projects/svn/gpucv/opencv_doc/2.1/opencv.pdf) description of `cvConvexityDefects` function.  Go read its description for information about how it's used.
- Once you have the convex hull, check the size of the defects.  4 of them should be approximately the same size (cause the fingers are the same length).  If that's the case, you have your open hand giving you a high five.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843089/shape-detection-using-matlab/4843136#4843136) - there is no straightforward, easy solution.